# Checking if a pair of strings contain the same characters?

Tags: java, string, character

I could use a txt file or enter through the Scanner class (which I will probably use), but I need to compare strings and check if they contain the same characters or not. If there are repeated characters it would still be true, for example, `abc` and `aaabbbccc` would be the same.

Comment: only same characters or could abc = aabbbcccdddeee?

Comment: Put characters from both strings to separate `Set<Character>` and compare their content.

Comment: only same characters. abc = aaabbbcccddee would be considered different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
//just call the checkChars method with 2 strings and it will check both strings to make sure
//that all the characters are contained in both strings.

public static void main(String args[]) {
         String test = "abc";
         String test1 = "abcaaabbc";
         System.out.println("" + checkChars(test, test1));
     }
     public static String checkChars(String string1, String string2)
     {
         boolean isContained = false;
         char[] char1 = string1.toCharArray();
         char[] char2 = string2.toCharArray();
         for(int i = 0; i < char1.length; i++)
         {
             isContained = false;
             for(int j = 0; j < char2.length; j++)
             {
                 if(char1[i] == char2[j])
                 {
                     isContained = true;
                     break;
                 }
             }
             if(isContained == false)
             {
                 break;
             }
         }
         if(isContained == true)
         {
             for(int i = 0; i < char2.length; i++)
             {
                 isContained = false;
                 for(int j = 0; j < char1.length; j++)
                 {
                     if(char2[i] == char1[j])
                     {
                         isContained = true;
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                 if(isContained == false)
                 {
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
         if(isContained)
         {
            return "Both strings contain the same characters.";
         }
         else
         {
            return "The strings have different characters.";
         }
     }
```

You can use the checkChars method for comparing 2 strings for the same characters.

Comment: I called it in my main method, but I'm wanting to return something like "Both strings are the same" instead of just true or false, would I need to set the return type as a String?

Comment: Oh got it, i had the if-else right I just had it returning it as System.out.print instead of just " ";

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not worried about the character counts, your problem is much simpler than a more usual question: *anagrams*. As Pshemo's comment notes, use `Set`s:

```
boolean hasSameChars(String s, String t) {
    Set<Character> sChars = new HashSet<Character>(Chars.asList(s.toCharArray());
    Set<Character> tChars = new HashSet<Character>(Chars.asList(t.toCharArray());
    return sChars.equals(tChars);
}
```

If you want to check if the number of characters is also the same in both strings, then use a `Map<String, Integer>` or `Multiset<String>` to keep track of counts.

To make the answer concise, I have used Guava, but the idea is clearly independent of Guava methods.

Answer (score 0):

With quick search on stack Overflow, I got this
Remove duplicate characters -> sort -> check if they are same

public static void main (String [] args){

```
    String s1 = "abc";
    String s2 = "aaabbbccc";

    System.out.println(check(dupRemove(s1), dupRemove(s2)));

}
static boolean check(String a, String b){
    char[] c1 = a.toCharArray();
    char[] c2 = b.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(c1);
    Arrays.sort(c2);

    return Arrays.equals(c1, c2);

}
static String dupRemove(String s){

    StringBuilder clean =  new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
        String j = s.substring(i, i + 1);
        if(clean.indexOf(j)==-1){
            clean.append(j);
        }
    }
    return clean.toString();
}
```